# How can I extend the bounty period?

Tags: support

Is it possible to extend the period of the bounty? If so, how can I do it?

Maybe I can extend the bounty period if I add more of the bounty?

I have set bounty on the question

[How do I restore a Virtualbox VM from backup? (qcow)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762548/how-do-i-restore-a-virtualbox-vm-from-backup-qcow)

and I hardly see any attention to it, still. I'm afraid the bounty will just expire and my hard-earned reputation that I set as a bounty will be wasted.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot extend the bounty period. Once the bounty expires you can re-bounty it with [bounty-amount]+50.

Comment: Does it mean that I'll be spending 50+100+... (another 100 on top of the first 50)?

Comment: no, it increments in amounts of 50. So 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, etc. It's been a while since I last set a bounty and I don't usually end up incrementing them, but this is how it works as far as I remember. You're always allowed to set *more*, just not <= the last bounty amount. So, if you count the previous bounty, two costs 150 (if that's what you meant).